# изменить путь в URL

Tags: xampp

где в xampp изменить путя, что бы не прописывая в дресной строке http://localhost/mysite а сразу http://mysite

Answer (score 1):

**C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.local
    DocumentRoot "C:\ПУТЬ\mysite.local\www"
    ServerName mysite.local
    ServerAlias www.mysite.local
    ErrorLog "C:\ПУТЬ\mysite.local\logs\error.log"
    CustomLog "C:\ПУТЬ\mysite.local\logs\access.log" combined
  <Directory "C:\ПУТЬ\mysite.local\www">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

```
127.0.0.1     mysite.local
127.0.0.1     www.mysite.local
```

Comment: Подскажите где в ubuntu найти? Этого пути не существует. А по "/opt/lampp/apache2/conf/httpd.conf" прописано другое:  Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>